# Android Studio Loop delay error

Tags: java, android, bucles

Quiero hacer un pequeño retraso cada vez que se hace un bucle, este es el código:

```
for (i = 0;i < n1; i++){
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(KeyMapCreator.this, "Try number " + i,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ActionIwantToDo();
        }
    },3000);
}
```

**La variable i** es la que el usuario proporciona, para ver cuantas veces se repite el bucle.
El problema esta en que aunque yo ponga 3 segundos o ponga 20 (por ejemplo), el toast y la acción ocurren seguidas sin ningún retraso, no se porque ocurre.
He probado a añadir un syncronized en caso de que sean muchos hilos que se ejecutan cada uno individual, y aunque cada uno espere esos segundos, todos van a la vez. No se como solucionarlo, si alguien sabe como puedo hacer correctamente un retraso dentro de un bucle por favor decirlo.

- He probado con `Thread.Sleep()` y con `SystemClock.sleep()`

Comment: Gracias por modificar tu pregunta!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No necesitas realizar un bucle, en realidad la variable i (es la que el usuario proporciona, para ver cuantas veces se repite el bucle) puede determinar el numero de veces que se mostraría el `Toast` y se realiza el proceso.

Define una variable a nivel de clase que fungirá como contador:

```
private int counter;
```

En base a esta variable puedes incrementarla cada vez que se muestra el `Toast` y se realiza el proceso.

```
            System.out.println("Loop: Conteo " + counter);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Try number " + counter,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            counter++; //incrementa contador
```

Al terminar puedes cancelar el Handler mediante:

```
 handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
```

---

```
    counter = 1;
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final int delay = 3000; //3 segundos

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){

            handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
            System.out.println("Loop: Conteo " + counter);

            Toast.makeText(KeyMapCreator.this, "Try number " + counter,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             ActionIwantToDo();

            counter++;
            if(counter > i){
                System.out.println("Loop: Termina proceso.");
                handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
            }

        }
    }, delay);
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias de verdad, funcionó, le añadiré unos if y poco mas para que termine de funcionar como yo quiero., solo me falta hacer que lo haga con la pantalla bloqueada pero creo que puedo hacerlo. Soy muy nuevo en esto de android studio